# JSON отправка кириллицы, Sting с русским текстом

Tags: json, swift, post

Отправляю запрос на сервер через заполнение формы из нескольких пунктов в UITextField, отправка происходит без проблем, если писать все на английском, как только в текстфилд попадает русский язык, при попытке отправить данные приложение падает на этом месте:

```
let postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
```

но приложение принимает данные и выводит русский текст в текстфилды, но в логах в юникоде приходит.

Нужно что бы отправка работала на двух языках: русском и английском.

Comment: вы думаете american standard code for information interchange содержит в себе кириллицу? :) вам надо не `NSASCIIStringEncoding` использовать а `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko капец, все решилось на раз, спасибо.
А как теперь будет правильно поступить с темой? удалить ее? ведь галочку напротив ответа некому ставить

Comment: сейчас перенесу коммент в ответ. Удалять не надо, я думаю еще много людей с этим столкнутся.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кодировка `NSASCIIStringEncoding` не содержит кириллических символов. Вам надо использовать `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Answer (score 1):

Если я все правильно понял то тебе нужно "заэнкодить" строку таким образом

```
let requestFilter = "Текст на русском"
let escapedString = requestFilter.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
let URL : String = Api.SERVER_URL + "=" + escapedString!
```

Удачи.